# Database SQL query to delete the duplicate emails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a SQL query to delete all duplicate email entries in a table named `Person`, keeping only unique emails based on its smallest Id. Id is the primary key column for this table.

This is the query I wrote:

```
delete from Person 
where Email not in (select distinct Email from Person)
```

But I get this error:

> You can't specify target table 'Person' for  update in FROM clause

Comment: So what's the problem? It's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Try This .

```
   DELETE p1 FROM Person p1
INNER JOIN Person p2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.Email = t2.Email ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySQL, which does not allow that syntax.  Use `join` instead:

```
delete p
   from Person p left join
        (select email, min(id) as min_id
         from person p
         group by email
        ) pp
        on pp.id = min_id
   where pp.min_id is null; --no match
```

Of course, your logic is wrong anyway.  But even with the correct logic, `not in`/`not exists` is not going to work in MySQL.  You need to use a join of some sort.

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IN` keyword after grouping the `Person` table to `Email`

```
delete from Person where id not in (
    select min(id) as ID from Person group by Email)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution